# Corda on AWS distributed

Tags: corda

I am trying to setup Corda on AWS with the nodes distributed across two machines. I have been following the instructions here:
https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html#running-nodes-across-machines

I have setup two servers on AWS using the Corda VM from the AWS Marketplace https://docs.corda.net/aws-vm.html

I note this seems to be Corda v1.0

I have downloaded the bootstrapper tool. I could not find the one for v1.0 so I downloaded the one for v3.0.

When I run it I get the following error:

```
Bootstrapping local network in /home/ubuntu/dev/cordapp-example/kotlin-source/build/nodes
Nodes found in the following sub-directories: [PartyB, PartyA, Controller, PartyC]
Waiting for all nodes to generate their node-info files...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node in PartyB exited with 1 when generating its node-info - see logs in /home/ubuntu/dev/cordapp-example/kotlin-source/build/nodes/PartyB/logs
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$gatherNodeInfoFiles$future$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:136)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$gatherNodeInfoFiles$future$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:44)
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:107)
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt)
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:119)
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$fork$$inlined$also$lambda$1.run(CordaFutureImpl.kt:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The log file shows the following:

```
Invalid command line arguments: just-generate-node-info is not a recognized option

Option                              Description                          
------                              -----------                          
--base-directory                    The node working directory where all 
                                  the files are kept (default: .)    
--config-file                       The path to the config file (default:
                                  node.conf)                         
--help                                                                   
--initial-registration              Start initial node registration with 
                                  Corda network to obtain certificate
                                  from the permissioning server.     
--log-to-console                    If set, prints logging to the console
                                  as well as to a file.              
--logging-level <[ERROR,WARN,INFO,  Enable logging at this level and     
DEBUG,TRACE]>                       higher (default: INFO)             
--no-local-shell                    Do not start the embedded shell      
                                  locally.                           
--sshd                              Enables SSHD server for node         
                                  administration.                    
--version                           Print the version and exit
```

Please can you assist. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Corda 1, one of the nodes on the network played the role of the Network Map Node. As a result, bootstrapping was not required.

In Corda 3, there is no Network Map Node, so bootstrapping is required. You can read about the rationale behind this decision here: https://medium.com/corda/cordas-new-network-map-infrastructure-8c4c248fd7f3.